# Настройка cisco 2960-S Series и маршрутизация Vlan

Tags: cisco

Принесли cisco, тыЖ программист и занимайся ей,пока уволился админ.
Можете подсказать, где взять рабочую мануалку по начальной конфигурации.

Смогу ли я c помощью данной cisco нарезать vlan 1 и vlan 2 сделать между ними маршрутизацию?
У меня есть  Vlan 23 192.166.23.1 сеть, хочу подсоединить к cisco и нарезать еще локальную сеть 192.166.24.1 Vlan 24(к примеру). Нужна отдельная локальная сеть.
Где можно прочитать рабочую мануалку?

Comment: См. здесь: https://www.ciscomanual.net/cisco-2960/. На русском можно почитать, например здесь: Ермаков А.Е., Основы конфигурирования корпоративных сетей Cisco, 2013г.

Comment: vlan'ы нарежешь...но это коммутатор....маршрутизация на 3 уровне

Comment: Смотри, вот [здесь](https://codeby.net/threads/roadmap-dlja-pentestera.74576/) есть настройки cisco от простого к сложному. Там несколько ресурсов, где ты сможешь взять для себя нужную информацию.